# Impala casting character to int giving null value

Tags: mysql, sql, impala

I have below table

[image]

I need a total_sales for each product and I am using the below query

```
SELECT product_id, sum(cast(trim(replace(replace(sales,'$',''),',','')) as BIGINT)) as total_sum FROM sales_data GROUP BY product_id;
```

when I am executing the above query getting **NULL** for total_sales. I tried *Int, Bigint, Smallint, tinyint* as well but getting the same issue. Can anybody pls help.

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: I never used Impala, but in MySQL, your query will work when using FLOAT instead of BIGINT.

Answer (score 1):

Well your sales amounts appear to be floating point values, not integers, so maybe you should cast to the correct type:

```sql
SELECT product_id, 
       SUM(CAST(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(sales, '$', ''), ',', '')) AS DECIMAL(20,2))) AS total_sum
FROM sales_data
GROUP BY product_id;
```

That being said, you should also probably store your sales figures in a numeric, rather than text, column going forward.

Comment: Pls replace `numeric` with `decimal`. Impala doesnt have numeric data type.

Comment: ...that change assumes the OP is using Impala and not MySQL, which however might be the case.

Comment: :) I see OP added both tags. Both are diff tools, OP need to correct it.

Comment: @KoushikRoy i changed it to decimal and it works. Thanks

Comment: @Uma Is green checkmark to the left possible?